# sorting table rows by columns containing markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the tablesorter JQUery plugin to sort the rows of a HTML table by clicking on a column. In most cases, the table cells contain simple markup like `<td>hello</td>`, so the default behaviour works fine.

However, one column of the table contains cells like this

```
<td>
  <a id="1" class="festivalSubscribe " action="create" 
    controller="festivalSubscription" onclick="/* Lots of Javascript */">Not Subscribed 
  </a>

  <a id="1" class="festivalUnsubscribe hide" action="delete" 
    controller="festivalSubscription" onclick="/* Lots of JavaScript */">Subscribed 
  </a>
</td>
```

Each cell of this column contains two links (as above), one of which will always be invisible (the one with the `hide` class). I want to sort this column by the visible link text ("Not Subscribed" or "Subscribed").

The plugin provides am option to define [a function](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html), the results of which will be used to determine how to sort the column, e.g.

```
textExtraction: function(node) { 
  // extract data from markup and return it  
  return node.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML; 
}
```

However, I can't find a way to define this function such that it will correctly sort the simple case `<td>hello</td>` and the more complex case described above.

Comment: maybe .innerText, so you only get actual text content and not tags?

Comment: what I want is the text of whichever link is not a member of the `hide` class, but I don't know how to express that in JQuery

Comment: You could use `node.textContent` for most modern browsers, however, for a few older browsers you have to use `node.innerText`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should handle both cases of having child elements and not having child elements:

```
textExtraction: function(node) { 
  // extract data from markup and return it  
  var $node_a = $(node).find("a");
  if ($node_a.length) {
    return $node_a.filter(":visible").text();
  }
  // normal case
  return node.innerHTML; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @Kevin B's answer is best for the original plugin, but I wanted to add that I have forked a copy of the original plugin on [github](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) and added functionality to the [textExtraction](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html) option to allow specifying columns. So this is possible.

```
$("table").tablesorter({ 

  // Define a custom text extraction function for each column 
  // default extraction is obtained like this: `$(node).text()` 
  textExtraction: { 
    0: function(node) {
      return $(node).find("a:visible").text();
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: That's a nice improvement. I was surprised this feature was not available in the original.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textExtraction: function(node) { 
    return $('td :not(.hide)', node).text(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab first visible element found inside the node and extract text from it using this:

```
$(node).find(':visible:eq(0)').text();
```